# Comment Box update time

Tags: reactjs, comments

I have an app wherein i have a comments box. Everything is working fine. However there is a small thing that is bugging me. I am using React and set the update Interval to 2 sec. So every 2 sec, a REST call is made which will return a new comment or no comment (i do this by sending last updated timestamp in the API call). However this rest call, is still returning 200 B, when empty. now on its own this size is minimal. But if a user stays on the page for 10 minutes, even with no new comments, he would download 10*60/2*200 B ~ 60000 B ~ 60 KB.

Is this considered appropriate or should i look into other solutions?

Comment: I think you could lower polling rate. Also, 60kb in 10 minutes is okay.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the input! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a websocket.

You can then poll your comments-source for changes from the server with no need to involve the browser. Only if you detect new comments *on the server* would you then broadcast an appropriate socket event with the payload. All listening clients would then update their comments only when required.

In this way you avoid any overhead, either the server load caused by creating and destroying the http connections, or client load receiving 'empty' payloads.

Comment: ok.. nice.. i read up on websockets and they do seem to solve the problem.. though i am lost on how to migrate the rest call to websocket.. i shall read more on this! thanks for the guidance.. :)